# Integration and limit

Tags: integration, limits

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Let $$f(x)=\frac 1{e^{x}+8e^{-x}+4e^{-3x}},\ g(x)=\frac 1{e^{3x}+8e^{x}+4e^{-x}},$$ and$$\int (f(x)-2g(x)) \,\d x=h(x)+c,$$where $c$ is the constant of integration, and $$\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)=\frac{\pi}4.$$ If $h(0)=\displaystyle \frac 1a\tan^{-1}\left(\frac bc\right)$ (where $a, b, c \in \mathbb N$, $b$ and $c$ are coprime), then find the value of $a+b+c$.

In this question I am not able to solve the integration. I am not getting any method.

Can anybody provide a hint?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to simplify $f(x)-2g(x)$?

Comment: @EclipseSun I think doing that it will become complicated

Comment: Where did you encounter this question?

Comment: @user377695 this question was given to me by my institution

Comment: Fiitjee? Allen?

Comment: Allen , why are you asking

Comment: it will not become complicated...as you said just an effort is what you needed

Comment: Were the last two terms in $1/g$ supposed to both be $e^{-x}$ terms?

Comment: @J.G. I have edited it now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I leave the details for you. Simplifying $f-2g$, we get
$$
\frac{e^{3x}-2e^x}{4+8e^{2x}+e^{4x}}.
$$
Integrating (let $t=e^x$), you will find that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\Bigl[\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}e^x\Bigr)-\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}e^x\Bigr)\Bigr]
$$
is a primitive function.

Can you take it from here?

**Update**

There is a simpler, but trickier, form, that one could obtain by writing $f-2g$ as
$$
\frac{e^x-2e^{-x}}{4e^{-2x}+8+e^{2x}}=\frac{D(e^x+2e^{-x})}{4+(e^x+2e^{-x})^2}=D\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\bigl(\frac{1}{2}(e^x+2e^{-x})\bigr)\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Integrating the simplified version seems tedious to me . can you please clarify how to integrate the simplified version

Comment: If it helps, the first inverse tangent result mickep gives can be converted to the second using the result: $\tan^{-1} u - \tan^{-1} v = \tan^{-1} \left (\frac{u - v}{1 + uv} \right )$.

Comment: @user377695 I updated with some steps (leading to an even simpler form). But it is trickier.